# Why is "if not someobj:" better than "if someobj == None:" in Python?

Tags: python

I've seen several examples of code like this:

```
if not someobj:
    #do something
```

But I'm wondering why not doing:

```
if someobj == None:
    #do something
```

Is there any difference? Does one have an advantage over the other?

Comment: Generally 'someobj is None' is preferable to 'someobj == None'

Comment: what about pseudocode if X is not None? Or `X != None`?

Answer (score 211, accepted):

In the first test, Python try to convert the object to a `bool` value if it is not already one. Roughly, **we are asking the object : are you meaningful or not ?** This is done using the following algorithm :

1. If the object has a `__nonzero__` special method (as do numeric built-ins, `int` and `float`), it calls this method. It must either return a `bool` value which is then directly used, or an `int` value that is considered `False` if equal to zero.
2. Otherwise, if the object has a `__len__` special method (as do container built-ins, `list`, `dict`, `set`, `tuple`, ...), it calls this method, considering a container `False` if it is empty (length is zero).
3. Otherwise, the object is considered `True` unless it is `None` in which case, it is considered `False`.

In the second test, the object is compared for equality to `None`. Here, **we are asking the object, "Are you equal to this other value?"** This is done using the following algorithm :

1. If the object has a `__eq__` method, it is called, and the return value is then converted to a `bool`value and used to determine the outcome of the `if`.
2. Otherwise, if the object has a `__cmp__` method, it is called. This function must return an `int` indicating the order of the two object (`-1` if `self < other`, `0` if `self == other`, `+1` if `self > other`).
3. Otherwise, the object are compared for identity (ie. they are reference to the same object, as can be tested by the `is` operator).

There is another test possible using the `is` operator. **We would be asking the object, "Are you this particular object?"**

Generally, I would recommend to use the first test with non-numerical values, to use the test for equality when you want to compare objects of the same nature (two strings, two numbers, ...) and to check for identity only when using sentinel values (`None` meaning not initialized for a member field for exemple, or when using the `getattr` or the `__getitem__` methods).

To summarize, we have :

```
>>> class A(object):
...    def __repr__(self):
...        return 'A()'
...    def __nonzero__(self):
...        return False

>>> class B(object):
...    def __repr__(self):
...        return 'B()'
...    def __len__(self):
...        return 0

>>> class C(object):
...    def __repr__(self):
...        return 'C()'
...    def __cmp__(self, other):
...        return 0

>>> class D(object):
...    def __repr__(self):
...        return 'D()'
...    def __eq__(self, other):
...        return True

>>> for obj in ['', (), [], {}, 0, 0., A(), B(), C(), D(), None]:
...     print '%4s: bool(obj) -> %5s, obj == None -> %5s, obj is None -> %5s' % \
...         (repr(obj), bool(obj), obj == None, obj is None)
  '': bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
  (): bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
  []: bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
  {}: bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
   0: bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
 0.0: bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
 A(): bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
 B(): bool(obj) -> False, obj == None -> False, obj is None -> False
 C(): bool(obj) ->  True, obj == None ->  True, obj is None -> False
 D(): bool(obj) ->  True, obj == None ->  True, obj is None -> False
None: bool(obj) -> False, obj == None ->  True, obj is None ->  True
```

Comment: Although technically correct, this does not explain that tuples, lists, dicts, strs, unicodes, ints, floats, etc. have a __nonzero__. It is much more common to rely on the truth value of built-in type than to rely on a custom __nonzero__ method.

Answer (score 56):

These are actually both poor practices.  Once upon a time, it was considered OK to casually treat None and False as similar.   However, since Python 2.2 this is not the best policy.

First, when you do an `if x` or `if not x` kind of test, Python has to implicitly convert `x` to boolean.  The rules for the `bool` function describe a raft of things which are False; everything else is True.  If the value of x wasn't properly boolean to begin with, this implicit conversion isn't really the clearest way to say things.

Before Python 2.2, there was no bool function, so it was even less clear.

Second, you shouldn't really test with `== None`.  You should use `is None` and `is not None`.

See PEP 8, [Style Guide for Python Code](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

> ```
> - Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with
>   'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators.
>
>   Also, beware of writing "if x" when you really mean "if x is not None"
>   -- e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to
>   None was set to some other value.  The other value might have a type
>   (such as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!
> ```

How many singletons are there?  Five: `None`, `True`, `False`, `NotImplemented` and `Ellipsis`.  Since you're really unlikely to use `NotImplemented` or `Ellipsis`, and you would never say `if x is True` (because simply `if x` is a lot clearer), you'll only ever test `None`.

Comment: The second form is categorically not bad practice. PEP 8 recommends using if x _twice_. First for sequences (instead of using len) and then for True and False (instead of using is).

Practically all Python code I've seen uses if x and if not x.

Answer (score 41):

Because `None` is not the only thing that is considered false.

```
if not False:
    print "False is false."
if not 0:
    print "0 is false."
if not []:
    print "An empty list is false."
if not ():
    print "An empty tuple is false."
if not {}:
    print "An empty dict is false."
if not "":
    print "An empty string is false."
```

`False`, `0`, `()`, `[]`, `{}` and `""` are all different from `None`, so your two code snippets are *not* equivalent.

Moreover, consider the following:

```
>>> False == 0
True
>>> False == ()
False
```

`if object:` is *not* an equality check. `0`, `()`, `[]`, `None`, `{}`, etc. *are* all different from each other, but they all *evaluate* to False.

This is the "magic" behind short circuiting expressions like:

```
foo = bar and spam or eggs
```

which is shorthand for:

```
if bar:
    foo = spam
else:
    foo = eggs
```

although you really should write:

```
foo = spam if bar else egg
```

Comment: Concerning your last question, they are equivalent.

Comment: And both incorrect because "" is False. The second one should read '("",) or ("s",)'. Anyway, modern versions of python have a proper ternary operator. This error-prone hack should be banished.

Answer (score 6):

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) recommends to use ***is*** or ***is not*** if you are testing for None-ness

> ```
> - Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with
>   'is' or 'is not', never the equality operators.
> ```

On the other hand if you are testing for more than None-ness, you should use the boolean operator.

Answer (score 3):

If you ask

```
if not spam:
    print "Sorry. No SPAM."
```

the *__nonzero__* method of *spam* gets called. From the Python manual:

> **__nonzero__**(*self*)
>     Called to implement truth value testing, and the built-in operation bool(); should return False or True, or their integer equivalents 0 or 1. When this method is not defined, __len__() is called, if it is defined (see below). If a class defines neither __len__() nor __nonzero__(), all its instances are considered true.

If you ask

```
if spam == None:
    print "Sorry. No SPAM here either."
```

the *__eq__* method of *spam* gets called with the argument *None*.

For more information of the customization possibilities have a look at the Python documenation at https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization

Answer (score 2):

These two comparisons serve different purposes. The former checks for boolean value of something, the second checks for identity with None value.

Comment: To be absolutely correct, the second checks for -equality- with a None value..."someobj is None" checks for identity.

Answer (score 0):

For one the first example is shorter and looks nicer. As per the other posts what you choose also depends on what you really want to do with the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is "it depends".

I use the first example if I consider 0, "", [] and False (list not exhaustive) to be equivalent to None in this context.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I chose a consistent approach across languages: I do `if (var)` (or equivalent) only if var is declared as boolean (or defined as such, in C we don't have a specific type). I even prefix these variables with a `b` (so it would be `bVar` actually) to be sure I won't accidentally use another type here.
I don't really like implicit casting to boolean, even less when there are numerous, complex rules.

Of course, people will disagree. Some go farther, I see `if (bVar == true)` in the Java code at my work (too redundant for my taste!), others love too much compact syntax, going `while (line = getNextLine())` (too ambiguous for me).