# Python: has_key , I want to print the value of the key with if statement

Tags: python

could you please help me with this.

I want to print the value of the key with if statement. it is have one OR other value if it is not , but not for one , for all.

my try:

```
wp = {'tomatos': , 'patotoes': , 'milk':0.5'cheese':, 'eggs':0.25,'meat':2}
x= ' item is not available in this store'
```

how I can make my output like this ?

> tomatos item is not available in this
>   store.
>
> patotoes item is not available in this
>   store.
>
> milk   0.5
>
> cheese item is not available in this
>   store .
>
> eggs 0.25
>
> meat 2

thats mean if any Item in the list dont have price , print x infront of it , and for others print the price shown .

Comment: Did you try typing your syntax in Python before posting the question? The dictionary syntax won't work as is.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of ways to do what you are asking but the below would work:

```
wp = { 'tomatos': None,
       'patotoes': None ,
       'milk':0.5,
       'cheese': None, 
       'eggs':0.25,
       'meat':2}
x= ' item is not available in this store'

for k,v in wp.items():
   print "%s%s" % (k, (v if v is not None else x))
```

Please not the changes to `wp`.

Comment: Can I do it without putting any value ?

Comment: I would suggest "is None" rather than "!=None"

@shz: You must supply some value for every key that you put into a dictionary.  "None" is the Python object which is conventionally used as a sentinel or placeholder for such things.  Presumably you were getting syntax errors from the attempts to execute that `wp=` statement in your example.

Comment: @Jim Dennis Any reason you suggest is None vs !=None?  jw.

Comment: @shz I do not know of any way to do it with out a value.

Comment: Why you should use `v is not None` explained here: [Why is if not someobj: better than if someobj == None: in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100732/why-is-if-not-someobj-better-than-if-someobj-none-in-python).

Comment: I originally had is not None, but figured it would be easier to read with != . (Reading your article now)

Comment: @Nix thank you very much.if I want to put value for each one , it will take too much time if I have a hug list of food name (for example), should be some way to fix it. but again thank you

Comment: How are you generating the dictionary?  By hand, I am sure there is a way to automate it.

Comment: @Nix you can often get away is != ... but when using None you almost always want to test identity rather than equality.  Incidentally if you want to create a sentinel object other than None you can use: mysentinel = object() and then test against that specific instance's identity.  (This would be for some hypothetical case where you need a sentinel but you might need to pass references to None on to some other API that might accept them.  Any object created by object() will have a unique identity, distinct from all other objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that the 'get' method of a dictionary returns None (by default) for a key that's not in the dictionary.

```
itemPrices = { 'milk' : 0.5, 'eggs' : 0.25, 'meat' : 2.0 }
sorry = 'Sorry, %s is not available in this store.'

for itemName in ('milk', 'potatos', 'eggs'):
    price = itemPrices.get(itemName)
    if price is None:
        print sorry % itemName
    else:
        print itemName, price
```

Comment: +1 good suggestion. `print itemName, itemPrices.get(itemName, "item is not available in this store.")`. This doesn't provide your nice string formatting, but demonstrates providing your own default to get.