# Python .get() does not evaluate to True even though there is an object?

Tags: python, pylons

I am running a Pylons project and ran into this strange problem. When submitting a form i have an option to add a logo (simple .png). The logo is passed in a FieldStorage instance. I try to evaluate if the logo was sent with this:

```
if request.params.get('logo'):
    do x
```

However, that always evaluates to False, even when there is logo. If I print request.params I get `UnicodeMultiDict([('logo', FieldStorage('logo', u'tux.png'))])`.

I solved it with:

```
if not request.params.get('logo') == None:
    do x
```

I fail to see why that works and the first example does not.

Comment: What does `bool(FieldStorage('logo', u'tux.png'))` return?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but according to pep8 you should use "is None" instead of "== None". See here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/q/100732/1205715

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is interesting, somehow the `FieldStorage` object resolves to false.

It is perfectly legal to write the following (a bit easier):

```
if request.params.get('logo') is not None:
    # do x
```

Answer (score 3):

With `request.params.get('logo')` you're getting a `FieldStorage` object, which probably evaluates to `False`, no matter what.

Anyway, you're just testing for existance of the `'logo'` key in the dictionary. Why don't you use dictionary semantics for that? Haven't checked, but I guess it supports something like:

```
if 'logo' in request.params:
    do x
```

Edit: had a look to the code. `UnicodeMultiDict` is a subclass from `UserDict.DictMixin`, so it implements `__contains__` and supports what I suggested.

Comment: Yes, that works fine as well. Still, I cannot see the logic in FieldStorage evaluating to False.

Comment: Go figure. `FieldStorage` is meant to be a general purpose storage, though, and as long as there's no defined behaviour for it when evaluating into a boolean, I there's no need for it to follow a certain logic.