# Python 'If not' syntax

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a bit confused about how/why so many python developers use `if not` in their conditional statements.

for example, lets say we had a function,

```
def foo(bar = None):
    if not bar:
        bar = 2
```

But why go about this way? I mean, wouldn't doing `if bar != None` or `if bar is not None`be more explicit? What does `if not` try to say?

Comment: This question has been asked before look here:   
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100732/why-is-if-not-someobj-better-than-if-someobj-none-in-python

Comment: Because 'if not' checks for truth and '!=' checks for equality.

Answer (score 279, accepted):

Yes, `if bar is not None` is more explicit, and thus better, assuming it is indeed what you want. That's not always the case, there are subtle differences: `if not bar:` will execute if `bar` is any kind of zero or empty container, or `False`.
Many people do use `not bar` where they *really do* mean `bar is not None`.

Comment: So if bar is `[]`, then it will execute?

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian Yes. Same or empty sets, tuples, dictionaries, strings, etc.

Comment: Wow that's really confusing

Comment: This is the best possible answer, bar none.

Comment: Better Answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34376465/10730632

Comment: @easeout :D :D :D