# Why is bool(x) where x is any integer equal to True

Tags: python

I expected `bool(1)` to equate to True using Python - it does - then I expected other integers to error when converted to `bool` but that doesn't seem to be the case:

```
>>> x=23 #<-- replace with any integer
>>> bool(x)
True
```

What is happening? Am I misunderstanding `bool(x)` - does this not convert x to a `Boolean` data type?

---

A lot of comments about why I find this counter-intuitive. If I write the above like the below then, on first sight with no knowledge of the language, it would seem counter-intuitive:

```
>>>True == bool(23)
True
```

Comment: `bool(-1)` is `True`. If you're talking about integers, only `bool(0)` is `False`.

Comment: You can also check it here for a bit more info: http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#bool

Comment: Why would you expect other integer values to be non-convertible to a bool?

Comment: You shouldn't assume that `True` has any particular non-zero value; it's an implementation detail that it has any integer value at all, let alone 1 specifically.

Comment: If you know that `bool(23)` is `True`, why would you not expect `True == bool(23)`?

Comment: @Kevin no - I'm saying if I knew nothing (not far of!) and saw `True == bool(23)` I'd be surprised to see it evaluate to `True`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From [5.1 Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

> The following values are considered false:
>
> - `None`
> - `False`
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`.
> - any empty sequence, for example, `''`, `()`, `[]`.
> - any empty mapping, for example, `{}`.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer `zero` or `bool` value `False`.
>
> **All other values** are considered **true** — so objects of many types are
>   always true.

Comment: +1 ok - I like this. At first glance to me it seems crazy ...just 0 amongst the integers that is False with every other being True. Now I see the answer though it seems ok - why should just 0==False, 1==True and all others be some sort of error: it's just a decision that the language designer makes.

Comment: @whytheq I wouldn't say it's a language specific thing. It's pretty common in programming world to denote `0` as `falsy`, and everything else as `truthy`. Things become easy to handle with this. For the reverse case though, `True` are always converted to `1`, and `False` to `0`. Some language however don't have such mapping from numeric values to boolean values, like `Java`.

Comment: @RohitJain There are languages that don't follow this though. In Ruby, `0` is not falsy. Only `false` and `nil` are treated as `false`.

Comment: @Cezar Yeah that's what I said in my last line. Same is true with `Java`. No mapping from numerical value to boolean value.

Answer (score 2):

`bool`'s purpose is not to convert a value to the bool data type, per se. Rather, it returns whether the value is truthy, i.e. it behaves in the same manner that this function does:

```
def bool_mimic(val):
    if val:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#bool):

> > bool([x])
> >
> > Convert a value to a Boolean, using the standard truth testing procedure [see [Rohit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19256012/15055)'s answer]. If x is false or omitted, this returns `False`; otherwise it returns `True`. `bool` is also a class, which is a subclass of `int`. Class `bool` cannot be subclassed further. Its only instances are `False` and `True`.

In the case of ints, the only non-truthy integer is `0`.

Comment: @Nirk: no, but it's relevant and it's a common convention to mark text that isn't in the original quote with square brackets. Hardly seems worth a downvote if that was you..

Comment: in retrospect a downvote probably wasn't warranted.  un-downvoted

Comment: +1 so more like a test of existence: although 0 exists. This doesn't exist = ()

Comment: @whytheq: hmm sort of. The method to override this behavior should give you a hint - it's called `__nonzero__`. then it's a matter of convention to define empty tuples & lists & dicts as "zero" and ones with elements in them as "nonzero". practically it makes for nice-looking code, IMO, but I'm also very used to it so I might be biased.

Answer (score 2):

`bool(x)` converts its argument to `Bool` by using the standard truth testing procedure. Anything that would return true on an `if` test, for example, will return `True` when passed as the argument to `bool`.

Check [Truth Value Testing](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) to see which values are treated as `True` or `False` in Python

Answer (score 1):

As other posters have mentioned, its giving true on any non-zero integer.

Its kind of similar to other things in python, like mentioned here:

[Python 'If not' syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739555/python-if-not-syntax)

(Rohit quotes a good paragraph about truth testing)