# "If not" condition statement in python

Tags: python, if-statement, conditional-statements

```
if not start: 
   new.next = None 
   return new
```

what does "if not" mean?
when will this code execute?

is it the same thing as saying
if start == None: then do something?

Comment: `if` is the statement. `not start` is the expression, with `not` being an operator.

Comment: @rnrneverdies although this is a great question, I don't think it speaks to the confusion OP is having (e.g. what does `if not` do?). Instead it talks about the distinction between `if <expr>`, `if <expr>==<value>`, and `if <expr> is <value>`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`if` is the statement. `not start` is the expression, with `not` being a [*boolean operator*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

`not` returns `True` if the operand (`start` here) is considered *false*. Python considers all objects to be true, unless they are numeric zero, or an empty container, or the `None` object or the boolean `False` value. `not` returns `False` if `start` is a true value. See the [*Truth Value Testing* section](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) in the documentation.

So if `start` is `None`, then indeed `not start` will be true. `start` can also be `0`, or an empty list, string, tuple dictionary, or set. Many custom types can also specify they are equal to numeric 0 or should be considered empty:

```
>>> not None
True
>>> not ''
True
>>> not {}
True
>>> not []
True
>>> not 0
True
```

Note: because `None` is a singleton (there is only ever one copy of that object in a Python process), you should always test for it using `is` or `is not`. If you *strictly* want to test tat `start` is `None`, then use:

```
if start is None:
```

Answer (score 0):

It executes when `start` is `False`, `0`, `None`, an empty list `[]`, an empty dictionary `{}`, an empty set...