# How do I test for null list entry in python list

Tags: python

I have a python list `[1,2,,4,5,6]`. What is the best method for testing for the missing, or `null`, list element? I am currently performing a `if element != ''` but I think there is a built-in test to perform such a thing, or am I wrong?

Comment: I tried entering  `[1,2,,4,5,6]` into my interpreter and got a `SyntaxError`. Can you show your actual code?

Comment: `if element ==  None`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Pythonic ways for checking for `None` or `null` are:

```
if element:
    # This is not null

if not element:
    # This is null
```

There is a very [detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100762/1401034) on the difference between `if not x` and `if x == None`.

### Edit 1:

Combining the comment and the other answers:

#### False Values

Python treats the following as `False` [source](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing):

- `None`
- `False`
- zero of any numeric type, eg: `0`, `0L`, `0.0`, `0j`
- any empty sequence, eg: `''`, `()`, `[]`
- any empty mapping, eg: `{}`
- instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a `__nonzero__()` or `__len__()` method, when that method returns the integer `zero` or bool value `False`

#### True Values

All other values are considered to be `True`.

#### Your question:

If you are indeed checking if `None` is present in your list (`[1,2,None,4,5,6]`) then @Poke 's answer is right:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6]
>>> None in lst
True
```

If you are wanting to check that the element is *only* `None` then @esauro is correct in the comments:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6]
>>> for x in lst:
...  if not x:
...    print(x)
None
```

But if your `lst` contains `0` (lst = [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6]) then your output will be `0`.

The only way you could get round this would be to explicitly check `if element is None`or `if element is not None`.

Comment: This is not exact. If `element` is 0 is not null, neither None, but `not element` would evaluate as True. In the same way if element is `[]` (an empty list) it would evaluate to True. Thus you should test `element is None` or  `not element is None`

Comment: Thank you @esauro - i've updated my answer based on your comment and Pokes answer

Answer (score 7):

If your list is `[1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6]` then you can just check `None in lst`, e.g.:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6]
>>> None in lst
True
```

Similarly, if you have some other value that represents a “missing” entry, you can just check `whatever in lst`.

Comment: I liked this one because it doesn't create a new list in the process of checking.

Answer (score 6):

> I have a python list [1,2,,4,5,6]. What is the best method for testing
>   for the missing, or null, list element?

If you just want to know if the list contains a [falsey value](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html) (that's the best equivalent for *missing or null* in Python), you can do this:

```
>>> all(x for x in [1,2,3,4,5])
True
>>> all(x for x in [1,2,'',4,5])
False
>>> all(x for x in [1,2,None,4,5])
False
```

If you want to know if a specific value exists that matches some condition:

```
all(x%2 for x in [1,2,3,4,5,7])
```

This will be true if the list contains all even numbers.

Comment: You do not need the `x for x in` part.  Also zero will treated as false.

Comment: You need the `x for x` if you want to test for something other than true or false.

Answer (score 1):

Find all the indexes where there is a `None` :

```
[i for i, item in enumerate(mylist) if item is None]
```

Example output :

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2, None, 4, 5, 6, None, None]
>>> [i for i, item in enumerate(mylist) if item is None]
[2, 6, 7]
```

Comment: Note that `None` should be compared using identity, not equality: `if item is None`...

Comment: @JonClements Can you point me to an explanation? I'm new to python.