# Python and is not None

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with this snippet of code:

```
if not fundbenchmark.endswith(("Index", "INDEX")) and fundbenchmark is not None:
    fundbenchmark = "%s%s" % (fundbenchmark, " Index")
```

Traceback:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Apparently this error appears when `fundbenchmark` is `None`. Implying that there is something wrong with `and fundbenchmark is not None:`

Am I correct in this assumption or is the explanation to be found elsewhere?

Comment: Just check if fundbechmark is not None first.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The boolean expressions in your `if` are [short-circuit evaluated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) left to right. What is wrong in your code is that you are applying the `is not None` condition *after* you have used the object. You need to invert the order of the conditions.

```
if fundbenchmark is not None and not fundbenchmark.endswith(("Index", "INDEX")):
```

Answer (score 3):

Expressions are evaluated in order. That means the `endswith` will be called first, before Python has a chance to check if the value is None.

You should swap the order of the checks.

Answer (score 1):

You did the check of None to late.

I would not write an explicit check for None, but use the object itself as boolean expression(See [Why is "if not someobj:" better than "if someobj == None:" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100732/) for more details about this).

```
if fundbenchmark and fundbenchmark.endswith(("Index", "INDEX")):
    fundbenchmark = "%s%s" % (fundbenchmark, " Index")
```

Comment: Worth noting that the semantics are a bit different here if f`undbenchmark` is a string or iterable. It evaluates to `False` if empty, not necessarily `None`. But in this case, it works.