# Why does 'if not None' return True?

Tags: python-3.x, nonetype

I'm having trouble understanding this

I tried:

```
if not None:
    print('True')
```

Why does it print True? 
Isn't the `None` type supposed to be `None`?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3289601/null-object-in-python

Comment: @Ralf17 That thread did not answer my question.

Comment: I imagine that you are getting down voted for a couple of reasons.  1) It doesn't appear that you have done a simple google search on your question to find the python documentation which very clearly states that `None` is evaluated as `False`.  2) Proofread.  "Why does it True?" is pretty sloppy grammar.

Comment: @Aaron I recommend that you should start reading a Python book to understand basic programming concepts. What you are asking is as simple and analogous to Arithmetic in Math. You can also go to https://www.python.org/doc/ to learn more about Python.

Comment: @Ralf17 Im learning from diveintopython3 and LPTHW.

Comment: @Check I am a new user, of course I will make mistakes, the least you can do is cut me some slack and tell me what I did before downvoting. And for the grammar, I moved the 'print' out of "Why does it print True" when moving around some text.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "if not someobj:" better than "if someobj == None:" in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/100732/why-is-if-not-someobj-better-than-if-someobj-none-in-python)

Comment: @Aaron yeah, proofread your text a bit. Use a quote in "I'm". Put in some effort

Comment: Well. it prints `True` because you literally tell the program to print "True".

Comment: Being used to SQL's NULL I find this question rather relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python `None` is a singleton. It is called the `null` in other languages.

In your `if not None:`, the compiler assumes that not None means non empty, or non-zero and we know an if statement evaluates non-zero values as `True` and executes them.

Function Examples:

1) `if not None:` prints argument x in test()

```
   def test(x):
       if not None:
           print(x)

   >>> test(2)
   2
```

2) `if 1:` prints argument x in test()

```
   def test(x):
       if 1:
           print(x)

   >>> test(2)
   2
```

3) `if -1:` prints argument x in test()

```
   def test(x):
       if -1:
           print(x)

   >>> test(2)
   2
```

4) `if 0:` does not prints argument x in test()

```
   def test(x):
       if 0:
           print(x)

   >>> test(2)
```

5) `if True:` prints argument x in test()

```
   def test(x):
       if True:
           print(x)

   >>> test(2)
   2
```

Comment: `None` is not the same thing as `null` in other languages. `null` is the absence of any value, `None` is itself a value. Python references always exist, and need something to be pointing to. The `None` object is a useful default. The Python compiler makes no assumptions about `None` whatsoever, it is the object itself that implements the `nb_bool` slot (the C-API equivalent of the [`__bool__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__), returning `0` (false). The pile of objects that are falsey is much larger than the examples you have given.

Answer (score 8):

**All** Python objects have a truth value, see [*Truth Value Testing*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). That includes `None`, which is considered to be *false* in a boolean context.

In addition, the `not` operator must *always* produce a boolean result, either `True` or `False`. If `not None` produced `False` instead, that'd be surprising when `bool(None)` produces `False` already.

The `None` value is a *sentinel object*, a signal value. You still need to be able to test for that object, and it is very helpful that it has a boolean value. Take for example:

```
if function_that_returns_value_or_None():
```

If `None` didn't have a boolean value, that test would break.

Answer (score 4):

[Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html)

> **4.1. Truth Value Testing**
>
> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> None
>
> False
>
> zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0.0, 0j.
>
> any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
>
> any empty mapping, for example, {}.
>
> instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **bool**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False.

Answer (score 1):

Each value has a property known as "truthiness". The "truthiness" of `None` is `False`. This is so for several reasons, such as clean code when you consider a return value of `None` to be failure or `False`.

"Empty" objects like `''`, `[]`, `0`, or `{}` all evaluate to false. Note that this doesn't include objects like `'None'` (the string) or `'0'`.

So `if not None` converts `None` to `False`.

"Truthiness" is also known as "booleaness", which is more formal in some contexts.

Answer (score 0):

[Irony mode on]

If you are not happy printing `True` you can make it print `False`:

```
if not None:
    print('False')
```

Now it prints False :)

**EDIT:** If you are worried about why it doesn't print `None` instead of `True` or `False` (or `Apples`) you can just make it print `None`:

```
if not None:
    print('None')
```