# How to assign a variable depending on a certain value in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program that involves assigning a string to the variable x depending on the length of the string assigned to variable y. The amount of commas in x should be the same as the length of y.

For example if `e='h'` , `x=','`. If `e='hi'` , `x=',,'`. If `e='him'` , `x=',,,'`

By the way, I'm new to programming so I don't know this stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is "if not someobj:" better than "if someobj == None:" in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100732/why-is-if-not-someobj-better-than-if-someobj-none-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

Invoke `len()` on `e` to get the length of the string and multiply that length by the string `,`, assigning it to `x`:

```
e = 'him'
e_length = len(e)
x = ',' * e_length
print(x)
```

This should yield `,,,`.

Answer (score 1):

Python allows you to multiply a string by a number to repeat it, which means you can do:

```
e = 'hello there'
x = ',' * len(e)
```

Which will give you:

```
',,,,,,,,,,,'
```