# Difference between if not: and if False:

Tags: python, boolean

I have a probably quite simple question but was wondering between the difference of these two statements:

```py
if not os.path.isfile(file):
  #Do some stuff
```

```py
if os.path.isfile(file) is False:
  #Do some stuff
```

What are the differences (if any) between the two? To my understanding they both return a `True` or `False` value, so is it just a matter of preference or are there any significant differences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Comment: *wow*, did this really require 6 answers (plus some deleted) when there is a wealth of better information on SO e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/100762/4711754

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python (and other dynamic languages) there is the concept of *truthy/falsy* value. `True/False` are not the only things that evaluate as true/false

```
if not []: 
   print("this will be printed")

if [] is False:
   print("this won't")
```

Another problem is that you should compare with `x == False`, and not `x is False`. The `False` is a singleton object in the current implementation of CPython, but this is not guaranteed by the specification.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, since we know `os.path.isfile` returns `True` or `False`, there is no difference.

In general, there are a lot of objects in python which, when interpreted as boolean, will evaluate to `False`.

Think of this:

```
empty_list = []
if not empty_list:
    print('List is not empty')
if empty_list is False:
    print('List is False')
```

Among the others, `None`, `""` and `[]` will evaluate to `False`.

So testing with `not variable` is usually the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

It's usually  better to use the first, since it works even if you're not checking an actual boolean value in a Python implementation where `False` is a singleton object.
Uniformity is good, and so is portability.

```
>>> if 0 is False: print "false"
>>> if not 0: print "false"
false
>>> if [] is False: print "false"
>>> if not []: print "false"
false
>>> if "" is False: print "false"
>>> if not "": print "false"
false
```

It also protects against mishaps like this:

```
>>> False = 1
>>> True == False
True
```

Answer (score 0):

You should know: `False == 0 == None` in case of `if` condition. If you use `if not`, you can cover all version of False (zero value). If you use `== False` you cannot handle the 0 or `None`. `if not` is recommended. The `is` operator is a different story (`is` not same as `==`) but you can read more details on this link: [Understanding Python's "is" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650293/understanding-pythons-is-operator)

Comment: Actually it does handle `0`, as it is treated as being falsey

Comment: False does not equal None

Comment: @yatu `False` and `0` are even more closely related than other falsey values, since `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: `None` is `NoneType` whether `False` is Boolean type.

Comment: I see your point, of course these values are not equal or same, but regarding to question in case of using `if not ...` condition doesn't matter that `0` or `False` or `None`.

Comment: @milanbalazs you should edit your answer to indicate that False == 0 == None in the case of if conditions.

Comment: Thanks @ AlexeyGy. I have update. Probably it's more understandable what I meant in my answer.