# Unless and Until in programming languages

Tags: until-loop, unless

What is the difference between

```
if (false == <condition>)
```

and

```
if (!<condition>)
```

and

```
unless (<condition>)
```

---

---

What is the difference between

```
while (false == <condition>)
```

and

```
while (!<condition>)
```

and

```
until (<condition>)
```

---

---

Why isn't `unless` and `until` in all programming languages?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Because for at least one programming language the language designers chose to not include it.

Comment: What these examples mean depends on the particular programming language you are referring to.

Comment: @mkrieger1: 

So, for example, Perl, but Perl does not have a boolean data type, and I can't think of another language. Please try to name one. :)

Comment: Python is another language.

Comment: @mkrieger1: So what is the difference between them in Python?

Comment: See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56257554/difference-between-if-not-and-if-false. But Python doesn't have unless and until.

Comment: @mkrieger1: And is there any other language besides Perl that has unless and until?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (false == <condition>)
```

and

```
if (!<condition>)
```

and

```
unless (<condition>)
```

Logically, they are all equivalent.

Likewise:

```
while (false == <condition>)
```

and

```
while (!<condition>)
```

and

```
until (<condition>)
```

Logically they are equivalent. Except syntactically, until() might be used at the end of a loop and while() at the beginning of a loop.

Although logically they are equivalent, some programming languages provide them (unless, until) for readability.

And you might want to take a look of [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/195279) to trace back their first usage in programming language.