# I am Facing a problem i Python where a user says "yes" or "no" the loop still executes anyhow. Why is it so?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, helper

I am making a python calculator program that asks a user after completing one calculation whether they want to continue or not. If the user says Yes the loop should run or else it should stop. I am Facing a problem where a user says yes or no the loop still executes anyhow. Why is it so ???

```
print("This is a Calculator In Python. !!!")
print("I Can Do Addition, Subtraction, Multiplication and Division.!!")

def addition():
    print("Please Don't Enter Float Values Here.")
    num1 = int(input("Enter First Number.!!"))
    num2 = int(input("Enter Second Number. !!"))
    result = num1 + num2
    return result
def subtraction():
    print("Please Don't Enter Float Values Here.")
    num1 = int(input("Enter First Number.!!"))
    num2 = int(input("Enter Second Number.!!"))
    result = num1 - num2
    return result
def multiplication():
    print("You Can Enter Float Values Here.")
    num1 = float(input("Enter First Number.!!"))
    num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number.!!"))
    result = num1 * num2
    return result
def division():
    print("You Can Enter Float Values Here.")
    num1 = float(input("Enter First Number.!!"))
    num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number.!!"))
    result = num1 / num2
    return result


print("""1. a for Addition
2. s for subtraction
3. m for multiplication
4. d for Division""")
select = "Yes"

while select:
  choice = str(input("You Choose The Operation."))
  if choice == "a":
    print(addition())
  elif choice == "s":
    print(subtraction())
  elif choice == "m":
    print(multiplication())
  elif choice == "d":
    print(division())
  else:
    print("Invalid Input")
  select=str(input('Continue Yes or No '))
print("Thank you..!")
```

Comment: You should check if ```select``` is equal to ```"Yes"```.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined your loop as `while select`, which means as long as select is considered to not be `None`, it will continue looping

In your loop, you assign the user input to `select`, which means as long as the user inputs anything, it will always keep looping.

To fix this, you should have the while loop check if `select` is "yes":

```py
while select.lower().strip() == "yes":
    choice = input("You Choose The Operation. ")
    if choice == "a":
        print(addition())
    elif choice == "s":
        print(subtraction())
    elif choice == "m":
        print(multiplication())
    elif choice == "d":
        print(division())
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
    select = input("Continue Yes or No ")
print("Thank you..!")
```

Also, `input()` returns a string so you don't need to wrap it in a `str()` call.

Comment: When converting to a boolean (which is done in ```while select```), ```0, (), [], None, {}``` all evaluate to False, not only ```None``` as you have written. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/100764/8359552).

Comment: I myself am aware of this, simply worded it poorly. Thanks for providing such a helpful link :)